# Two plugins have the same class name flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am importing the
***permission_handler*** plug-in and the
***location*** plug-in.
The problem is that both of these have a class called PermissionStatus, and I need to use PermissionStatus.granted from the ***location*** plug-in, since I am requesting permission to access location from the ***location*** plug-in. So what I need someone to explain to me is either
***a)*** How to fix the problem of using a class from one plugin, that happens to be in another plugin I imported under the same name.

or

***b)*** How to properly request permission for access to location using only ***permission_handler***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have import two `libraries` that have conflicting identifiers, then you can specify an `import prefix` for one or both `libraries`.

For example, if `library1` and `library2` both have an `Element` class, then you might have code like this:

```
import 'package:lib1/lib1.dart';
import 'package:lib2/lib2.dart' as lib2;

// use in your code like
Element libraryOneElement = Element(); // from library one
lib2.Element libraryTwoElement = lib2.Element(); // from library two
```

A demo using your code as an example:

```
import '...permission_handler...';
import '... location...' as location;

// use in your code like
var permissionHandlerStatus = PermissionStatus.granted;
var locationPermissionStatus = location.PermissionStatus.granted;
```

Comment: This is awesome! Than k you very much, but I would also like to know an answer to part b. Its ok if you dont anwser just asking for anyone

Comment: What do you mean by `properly` ?

Comment: Oh I mean to request permission only using permission handler, such that it actually works and doesn’t crash my app.

Comment: I guess that should be another question @arch, Your question should focus on only one problem. If my answer helped you solve the issue specified in your question, please accept it.